# Trying to pass a long value from a div when calling a function(html5/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<div id="div1" value="3" onclick="Function(this.id,this.value)"></div>
```

`this.id` works but not the second argument. Been googling around but no luck, so I resorted
to start my own thread, hopefully you can help!

NOTE: That I don't wanna send what's inside the `div`, I want to send the second attribute (`Value="3"`).

Answer (score 1):

Did u try the following:

```
theElement.getAttribute("Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use jquery? try this `$('#div1').attr('Value')` or `$('#div1').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but generally you can retrieve attributes like this:

```
element.getAttribute("Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're confusing property with attribute. Some standard attributes are available as properties, but nonstandard ones are generally not.

By the way, it's better (valid and more future-proof) to use `data-` prefixed attributes instead of nonstandard nonprefixed attributes for storing arbitrary data.

Your example can be correctly rewrited following way:

```html
<div id="div1" data-value="3" onclick="Function(this.id,this.getAttribute('data-value')"></div>
```

Comment: That sounds like what I wanna do, now if I want to change "data-value" in that div from a different function(in javascript) which gets called on pageload. Basically I have a function that gives out random numbers to a number of divs. If you could give me the line that let's me change that value; for example = document.getElementById(div-id).data-value

Comment: `document.getElementById('someId').setAttribute('data-value', 3);`. By the way, consider learning more about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) in general.

Comment: Will do sir, It's part of a schoolproject in a course I just started so im a bit rusty, but thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Consider marking an answer you're most satisfied with as solution for your question.